# Panel con el icono en la izquierda bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

amigos una consulta, como puedo hacer un panel como el siguiente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el icono en el lado izquierdo?

Comment: Existen muchas maneras para hacerlo. ¿Podrías mostrarnos lo que estás intentando para poder ayudarte desde el punto dónde te quedaste?

Comment: Hola Luis, imagino que esta pregunta esta relacionada a esta que realizaste : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179286/aviso-en-la-pantalla?noredirect=1 te sugiero realizar preguntas basadas en [ask] y te aseguro obtendrás la ayuda deseada, saludos-.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="col-3" style="background: green">
                        Icono aqui
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        Texto aqui
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
</body>
```

Comment: 2 cosas gracias por tu apoyo respondiendo sin embargo, tu respuesta carece de explicación por lo cual será vista como de baja calidad y segundo preguntas que solo0 piden que se les hagan las cosas no se deben responder

Comment: ahh, bueno disculpa. borro la respuesta?

Comment: Alfredo Paz, no entiendo tu problema? solo estoy preguntando por un codigo que no lo encuentro por internet ?, Si alguien pregunta como se subraya un texto o como lo hago mas grande, tengo que pedirle todo su código para ayudarlo?, si no estas dispuesto apoyar. Anda a otro lugar.

Comment: @LuisVega no es problema mio asi funciona el sitio, debes mostrar lo que hayas tratado no solo pedir como se hace algo, los 4 puntos negativos en tu pregunta los hicieron 4 personas distintas entonces no solo soy yo

Comment: @Teovilla Gracias por tu contribución, pero como comenta Alfredo, responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad. Además recuerda agregar una explicación de lo que realiza el código, revisa [answer], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Hola, tras la respuesta de Alfredo he revisado el articulo de Como responder. Gracias, estoy tratando de mejorar mis preguntas y respuestas en el sitio, gracias.

Comment: @Teovilla te agradecemos las contribuciones en el sitio, son valiosas para todos y más aún si las realizas como dicta el [help], muchas gracias!